# Using Seaborn countplot error using sns.categorical._CountPlotter

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to add `countplot` to an existing python module, [statannotations](https://github.com/trevismd/statannotations), to allow for chi-squared tests and I'm getting an error message that I am unable to debug.

I can create the plot just fine using `countplot`:

```py
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.countplot(data=titanic, x="class", hue="who")
```

However, when I try to access the `countplot` from the class I am getting the following error:

```py
sns.categorical._CountPlotter(data=titanic, x='class', y=None, hue='who', 
                              order=None, hue_order=None, estimator=np.mean, 
                              ci=95, n_boot=1000, units=None, seed=None, 
                              orient=None, color=None, palette=None, 
                              saturation=.75, errcolor=".26", errwidth=None, 
                              capsize=None, dodge=True)
```

```py
*** TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Any ideas of where to begin approaching this?

Comment: Maybe `estimator=len` instead of `estimator=np.mean`?

Comment: But you better set `ci=None` to avoid the slow and unnecessary bootstrapping.

Comment: Using the ```estimator=len``` did bypass that error.  What does changing the confidence interval to ```None``` actually do?

Comment: I'm not sure for this exact function, but for bar plots when there are multiple values corresponding to an x-value, a confidence interval of 95% is calculated via bootstrapping (1000 times in the default `n_boot=1000`). The ci provokes the traditional error bars, which don't make sense here. The estimator is used as a function that reduces an array of values to 1 value. If you want to use this in a library, you probably want to set `ci=None, n_boot=0` as it really slows things down for large arrays.  (Probably Michael isn't very fond of private functions being used outside of seaborn ...)

Comment: Side note, you should definitely not be using a private class directly in your library, unless you want it to break without warning when your users update seaborn.